# How to get Microsoft Graph access token using email id in the skype for business bot to add an event to Calendar

Tags: botframework

In Skype for Business Bot , User is pre-authenticated, need to get Microsoft graph access token , in order to perform Microsoft Graph operations (such as adding events to calendar) in programmatic way..

Please suggest how Microsoft Graph Apis can be integrated with Azure Bot for Skype for business channel.

We want Skype for Business bot to book the meeting just like described [here](https://microsoftapac.github.io/bot%20framework/2017/03/17/CRESCO.html)

But instead of Teams need to use Skype for Business. but basically this code line will ask user to explicitly in this code sample 
"await context.Forward(new AzureAuthDialog("

There is another sample that need Adminconsent to update the calendar of specific user 
Swati

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reuse anything from the pre-authentication. Like any other channel, you have to go through a specific authentication phase.

You have a great sample on the official repository to do this, here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph